# AIMD simulation of a silica slab and a electrolyte placed in the vacuum region

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, aimd

Can someone share a VASP input file as a template that I can use to equillibrate a system as mentioned in the title. I created one but I am not sure if that is correct or not.

```
SYSTEM   = AIMD on silica slab surface 
 NWRITE   = 2      #
 PREC = Normal     #

# electronic degrees
LREAL = A                      # real space projection
PREC  = Normal                 # chose Low only after tests
EDIFF = 1E-5                   # do not use default (too large drift)
ISMEAR = 0 ; SIGMA = 0.130     # Fermi smearing: 1500 K 0.086 10-3
ALGO = Fast                    # recommended for MD (fall back ALGO = Fast)
MAXMIX = 40                    # reuse mixer from one MD step to next
ISYM = 0                       # no symmetry
NELMIN = 4                     # minimum 4 steps per time step, avoid breaking after 2 steps
# MD (do little writing to save disc space)
IBRION = 0                     # main molecular dynamics tag
NSW = 1000                    # number of MD steps
POTIM = 1.0                    # time step of MD
NWRITE = 0                     # controls output
NBLOCK = 10                    # after ten steps pair correlation function is written out
LCHARG = .FALSE.               # no charge density written out
LWAVE = .FALSE.                # no wave function coefficients written out
TEBEG = 298                    # starting temperature for MD
TEEND = 298                    # end temperature for MD
# canonic (Nose) MD with XDATCAR updated every 10 steps
MDALGO = 2                     # switch to select thermostat
SMASS =  3                     # Nose mass
ISIF = 2                       # this tag selects the ensemble in combination with the thermostat
NCORE = 4                      #
IVDW   =  10                   #                                                                                                                           

VDW_RADIUS = 10.0              #                                                                                                                           

GGA   = PE
```